# Mathematical quiz

Tags: math, graph

I do have a pairs "`manager`, `worker`" for some hierarchy structure.
What will be the total number of relations "`manager, worker`" including relations like "`manager, worker of my worker - my worker`", "`worker of worker of my worker - my worker`" and so on...

For example:

```
Alex, Pete
Pete, Kane
Jones, Alex
Clark, Allen
```

The total amount of connections is 7:

```
Jones -> Alex -> Pete -> Kane
Jones -> Pete
Jones -> Kane
Alex -> Kane
Clark -> Allen
```

I have to calculate the total amount of connections for about ~20k relations.
Is there any special methods for doing so?

Comment: are there any restrictions about how many direct managers a worker can have or vice versa?

Comment: also i suppose, cycles are not allowed. am i right? any other restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

i think there cant be a mathematical solution without analyzing the stucture.
and if you have analyzed it it is straight forward to count them.
here is a solution in delphi, but you can easily translate it in any other language. you only have to fill the dictionary with your source of the 20k pairs.

```
program Project1;

uses
  Generics.Collections;

function relationcount(dict:TDictionary<string,string>):Integer;
  function _relationcount(_key:string):Integer;
  begin
    if dict.ContainsKey(_key) then
      result:=1+_relationcount(dict.Items[_key])
    else
      result:=0;
  end;
var k:string;
begin
  result:=0;
  for k in dict.Keys do
    result:=result+_relationcount(k);
end;

var
  relations:TDictionary<string,string>;
begin
  relations:=TDictionary<string,string>.Create;

  // replace this with your read from file algorithm //
  relations.Add('Alex', 'Pete');                     //
  relations.Add('Pete', 'Kane');                     //
  relations.Add('Jones', 'Alex');                    //
  relations.Add('Clark', 'Allen');                   //
  // ----------------------------------------------- //

  writeln(relationcount(relations));
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure there's a solution. Essentially you're asking for the sum of the number of supervisors each person has. So you could do something as simple as

```
s = 0
for each worker w
  for each worker v
    if v is above w in the supervisory chain then s <- s+1
return s
```

Depending on how your data is stored and what language you are using there might be a more efficient way of doing this.